# strsplit intermediate pattern in first column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, split, apply, sapply

I have a data frame and I would like to split the first column into two columns but the separate pattern is similar to others and I only want to split the pattern located on number 4.

```
data frame:
TCGA-TS-A7P1-01A-41D-A39S-05     0.8637304    
TCGA-NQ-A57I-01A-11D-A34E-05     0.7812147    
TCGA-3H-AB3O-01A-11D-A39S-05     0.8963944    
TCGA-LK-A4O2-01A-11D-A34E-05     0.6942843    
TCGA-MQ-A4LI-01A-11D-A34E-05     0.8882558    

desired output:
TCGA-TS-A7P1-01A    41D-A39S-05    0.8637304    
TCGA-NQ-A57I-01A    11D-A34E-05    0.7812147    
TCGA-3H-AB3O-01A    11D-A39S-05    0.8963944    
TCGA-LK-A4O2-01A    11D-A34E-05    0.6942843    
TCGA-MQ-A4LI-01A    11D-A34E-05    0.8882558
```

I tried:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$ID), "-"), '[', 1:4)
```

However, it is not the desired output above that I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one and it worked well.

```
df <- cbind(df[,1],df)
df[,1] <- substr(df[,1],1,16)
df[,2] <- substr(df[,2],18,28)
```

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus oh yes, I have many columns behind. so this one df <- df[, c(1,3,2)] not really works but thanks a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If this is going to be your fixed format always, you can use this. However, this is very risky. 1 character here and there and this is going to fail.

Comment: @RonakShah yea I think so, is there any other solutions ? I tried to use sapply but simply I can't work it out so I m going to do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

It seems all the elements of your first column are of the same length so one simple way could be:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("TCGA-TS-A7P1-01A-41D-A39S-05","TCGA-NQ-A57I-01A-11D-A34E-05","TCGA-3H-AB3O-01A-11D-A39S-05"),
                 col2 = c(0.8637304,0.7812147,0.8963944), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$col1bis <- substr(df$col1,18,28)
df$col1 <- substr(df$col1,1,16)
```

Then I reaggange the order of the columns:

```
df <- df[, c(1,3,2)]
```

resulting in:

```
> df
              col1     col1bis      col2
1 TCGA-TS-A7P1-01A 41D-A39S-05 0.8637304
2 TCGA-NQ-A57I-01A 11D-A34E-05 0.7812147
3 TCGA-3H-AB3O-01A 11D-A39S-05 0.8963944
```

Comment: Ty for the edit, it's simplier and correct at least.

Comment: `arrange` is for ordering the rows. If you want to change the column order with `dplyr`, you can use `select`, e.g.:  `df %>% select(col1, col1bis, col2)`